# React style element descendant selector

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to use the direct descendant CSS selector in a React inline style element:

```js
 <style>{`
  .something>div{
    color: blue;
  }
`}</style>
```

This is working fine on dev but in prod, React (un)helpfully converts the > into a `gt;`, screwing up my CSS.

How can I do a direct descendant in a React inline style element?

Alternatively, how can I get React to treat the innerHTML as literal?

I have a React app with multiple files and pages using Gatsby, which is notorious for not allowing multiple different CSS for different pages. I'm also using nested React components, so giving the nested components classes is not an option without modifying node_modules.

Comment: Are you using a styling library?

Comment: nope. why the extra dependency when you can not

Comment: but i have used styled before and it might fix the problem... or it might not

Comment: I thought you were you using a styling library because I haven't since `<style>` elements used like that. Didn't even know it would work till I tried today. Learn something new every day. You could just add your code to your global css stylesheet?

Comment: i don't have a global CSS because gatsby puts the global stylesheet on every single page, which absolutely messes up my styles :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `styled-components`, you can write style like native css with it.
e.g.

```js
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const ToTop = styled.button`
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    polyline {
        stroke:#000;
        ${otherStyles}
    }
    &: hover{
        background: #dcc9c9;
    }
`

export default () => (
    <ToTop />
)
```

About InnerHTML, see [this doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: neat
i will definitely use this newfound power responsibly ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're insisting on using child selectors in CSS with style tags, you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property of a jsx (in this case, style) element:

```
<style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={`
div>p{
 color:blue;
}
`}/>
```

Comment: The syntax is dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:html}}.